# Merge pull request to a different branch than default, in Github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

A pull request comes into my repo hosted on Github. By default it is merged into the `master` branch.

Is there any way for me to change which branch the changes would be merged into?

Comment: AFAIK on GitHub there is no way to change the **default** branch that pull requests for different branches merge to because GitHub only has a single concept of a "base" branch which it uses for everything. You have to change it manually every time.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

[As of 15.08.2016](https://github.com/blog/2224-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) GitHub allows changing the target branch of a pull request via the GUI. Click `Edit` next to the title, then select the branch from the dropdown.

[image: screenshot]

> You can now change the base branch of an open pull request. After you’ve created a pull request, you can modify the base branch so that the changes in the pull request are compared against a different branch. By changing the base branch of your original pull request rather than opening a new one with the correct base branch, you’ll be able to keep valuable work and discussion.

Comment: This feature doesn't seem to exist anymore (as of 2018-02-15), does it? In a recent pull request the target branch is displayed in the same blue font on light blue background as the source repository/branch and not a button anymore.

Comment: Ah! It does! One first needs to click on "Edit" (which is not obvious from the above screenshot). I overlooked this. Sorry.

Comment: @cgogolin Thanks for pointing that out – I was confused too, until I read your comment and clicked on the Edit button.

Comment: [Github warns](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) that "When you change the base branch of your pull request, some commits may be removed from the timeline." and "Some commits from the old base branch may be removed from the timeline." Any idea what this means?

Comment: But you still can't create a _new_ branch to merge into.

Comment: Does this still work? When I open the drop-down for branches in either repo, I get a search field but no matched branches whatsoever and hitting enter doesn't select it either even when completely and correctly spelled, so I'm very confused.

Comment: What the warning about "commits from the old base branch may be removed from the timeline" means is that the timeline (the list of which commits are included in that PR) may change if you changes branches (in the case where some of the commits in the PR already existed in the newly selected branch)

Answer (score 55):

The submitter can change that when they issue the pull request, but once they issue it you can't change it.

On the other hand, you can manually merge their branch and push, which I semi-regularly do for mistargetted pull requests.

You may find the [`hub` gem](http://github.com/defunkt/hub) helpful in working with the components of the pull request.

That gem wraps up the manual process, which is:

1. [Add a remote](http://help.github.com/remotes/) for the fork to your local checkout.
2. Fetch that remote.
3. `git checkout ${target_branch} && git merge ${remote}/${branch}`
4. `git push origin ...`

Comment: If I manually merge and push, will Github realise that the pull request has been effectively completed? Any pointers on how to merge from a remote separate repo (the fork)?

Comment: I am not sure, but not directly - because the change didn't merge into the target branch, so the pull request is not completed as defined.  You need to manually close it.  As to the pointers, see the edited comment.

Comment: I'd recommend using `git merge --no-ff ...` as @GuillermoMansilla mentions in his answer.

Comment: "Once they issue it you can't change it" - No longer the case as of August 2016! See @maliayas 's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38985999/12484

Comment: I followed this procedure today (Mar 3 2017). I downloaded pull request into another branch and made some additional fixes to it, then merged to master. Once commits from the pull request ended up in master, GitHub automatically closed the pull request.

Answer (score 16):

An alternative to using the hub gem mentioned by other answers is to [use the command line to merge locally pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), which allows you to do:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout *target_branch*
$ git merge pr/XXX
$ git push origin *target_branch*
```

---

The commands above only work directly if you first add the following line to your `.git/config` file:

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/symbolic_name_origin_or_upstream/pr/*
```

What that does is allow you to download **ALL** pull requests. Since that may not be desired for huge repos, GitHub modified the instructions to feature the `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` syntax, which avoids modification of the configuration file and only downloads that single pull request.

Answer (score 10):

Although you cannot change the existing pull request as it is not yours, you can easily create a new one if the related source repository still exists - yes, even if it is someone else's.

Go to the repository of the submitter then create a new pull request in his/her repository using the same commits but make sure you set the right target branch correctly.

Then go back to your own repository and accept the new pull request. Voila!

Comment: Does this work if they have changed their repository?  How does one ensure that it's "the same commits?"

Comment: @ragerdl - If you're developing using a 'feature-per-branch' model, then you can create a PR with a branch against an upstream branch, and it should contain the same commits.

Comment: The only way to do it directly on GitHub, without access to a local repo.

Comment: Underrated solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with Daniel Pittman's solution, however I would treat those merges as "no fast forward", that is, changing step number 3 for:

```
git checkout ${target_branch} && git merge --no-ff ${remote}/${branch}
```

By using `--no-ff`, the history will be easier to read. It will clearly say that `$n` commits came from `$branch`, and it will also make your life easier if you need to revert something done in that branch.

To also answer eoinoc's question and give an additional tip:

After doing the merge, your git cli will prompt you to write a message, generally a generic message will show up saying something like

> Merge remote-tracking branch 'user/their-branch' into your-branch

Make sure to edit that message and include a reference to the pull request number. That is:
(Assuming the pull request number is 123)

> Merge remote-tracking branch 'user/their-branch' into your-branch
>
> refs #123 solving whatever...

So next time you visit your github issues/pull-requests page and check that particular pull request, you will see your message with a link to commit where you did the merge.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To do that go to your repository's home page, click on branches, and change the default branch from master into something else, in my case "dev".

After that, whenever someone creates a pull request the `merge` button will automatically merge the request into "dev" rather than master.

[image]

Comment: This is flagrant negligence to promote this change without warning about the consequences. GitHub uses their "base branch" or "default branch" concept across the board for many purposes and changing it can adversely affect the operation of your repository. -1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068495/what-are-the-consequences-of-making-develop-the-default-branch-on-github