# How do I "patch" my website without the fear of breaking something?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a website, and im doing it on its final destination domain, not on localhost, and its almost finished.

Now I've come to the point where I'm beginning to get worried about what I do when users start using the site and some problems occur, or maybe I want to add a features to the site.

Is there any best practices which will allow be to minimize risks ruinin website and customer UX during updates, how to do it correctly?

Comment: version control ?

Comment: There is generally  a production environment, a staging environment (which should mimic the intended production environment), and local developer environments.  You test each as you progress before deploying code to the next level (development -> staging -> production).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website is small and easy:

1. Create a development domain/subdomain
2. Code and test there
3. Record all database structure changes (do database changes on a db copy)
4. Record your actions you use to test your website
5. As soon as you are ready to release a new version there are two options:

   1. Update db replica and switch domains
   2. Turn main domain off, update code and db, turn on

If website is not that easy, there should be local development, testing, staging and production environments set up independendly. You dev, then you test what you did, then you copy and install your code on real data before pushing it live on production.

[image: dev-stage-prod]

To track changes and easily deploy new version to each of environments there are many tools connected with version control systems like **git**

And there is a good answer on how to use dev-test-stage-production environments with git: [git with development, staging and production branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072243/git-with-development-staging-and-production-branches)

Comment: Perfect, I was also beginning to think about developing on a test domain. Recording database structure changes will feel like slave work, is there a way to make the process more automatic? syncing changes or something. im using mysql

Comment: Updated with environment structure and link

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to work on localhost, while developing any new feature, of fixing a bug.
I recommend you also to use GIT branches, so you can create a new branch to add feature of fix a bug.
After finish use GIT merge with your website master branch

Comment: nice! i didnt know about that feature of git! thanks a lot mate

Comment: GIT helps you to track your website changes, also store a copy on a remote server (called Remote repository), such as Github.com or Bitbucket.org, go to www.git-scm.org