# create a new pull request from existing commit for different branch for github

Tags: github

I have create a new branch and made some changes then I committed it.
Raised a pull request to merge into master. but now client wants me to create new pull request for different branch other then master with complete conversation history.

Comment: [Merge pull request to a different branch than default, in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135913/merge-pull-request-to-a-different-branch-than-default-in-github) ?

Comment: Thanks @RomanGotsiy yes it is a good answer, but the problem is, client do not want me to create a new branch he just need a new pull request for the same commit(may be by using same token number which I had used first time) with all the conversation history .