# default branch for pull request

Tags: github

My company uses github.  When I want to do a pull request I need to make my PR from my fork to the main repo into the staging branch.  By default my PRs point to the master branch, so for every pull request I have to change which branch I'm merging into.  I know that you can set the default branch in github.  I want the default branch to remain master, but I want my pull requests to point to staging by default.  Is that possible?

In the image below I don't want to have to change `base: master` to `base: staging` every time. The bigger pain is when I forget to change it to staging.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to settings page, branches, ... and select the default branch.

[image]

Comment: Are there downsides to not having the default branch being master?  Otherwise, this is exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: The downside is that this is also the cloning branch. It forces us to use the devel branch as our main branch. It also might interfere with some bots such as "wei/pull".

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing the default branch? For ex the default branch is `main`, but new PRs are compared to `develop` by default (not `main`).

Comment: I dont think. Your PR are against the default branch. Why do you need this stuff?

Comment: @sensorario its quite common to attempt to have a team merge to a staging branch before main. Some individuals who are newer to PRs may not understand how to do this immediately and as such you can merge new code into the wrong "testing" branch before stability checks pass.

Comment: _> Why do you need this stuff?_

It would permit to show by default the code that corresponds to the latest release to people that open the repo, instead of the code that is still being tested.

Comment: Yes there are downsides. GitHub uses the default branch for everything. This is probably not the solution you want for defaulting PRs. I don't think GitHub supports it. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068495/what-are-the-consequences-of-making-develop-the-default-branch-on-github. GitLab has had this as a feature request open for over 6 years it seems (possibly around 8 years) and if I'm not mistaken seems to be working on it right now !! https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17909 