# Git: Simulate PR merge and test it

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

We have a PR, it is working ok, however the PR has a very old version of the origin branch, the origin branch has been updated a lot since the PR branch was created.

So How can I "simulate" the merge and run tests before actually merge to the origin branch?

Comment: ...merge into another branch that's at the same place as the branch in which you want to eventually commit? Git doesn't have a concept of "simulate a merge".

Comment: just create a new branch for your testing.

Comment: Incidentally, why not use a continuous integration tool?

Comment: @dr_debug ho so you mean create the branch, then manually merge the PR?

Comment: @JackManey would be useless since we don't have automated testing (we are on it) lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replicate your branch pointer by just doing the following from your development branch:

```
git checkout -b test-branch
```

Now you are in `test-branch`, which is identical to your development branch. Go ahead and merge (or better yet, rebase) onto the current master branch:

```
git merge master
```

OR

```
git rebase master
```

You may have to resolve some conflicts along the way. Git will print clear instructions on how to do so if that happens. Now `test-branch` is merged on top of master, starting where your development branch first diverged. Your development and master branches are untouched by this operation.

If you are happy with the merge, you can delete `test-branch` or move the development branch to the merge point using `git branch`:

```
git branch -f development test-branch
```

Keep in mind that if your original master branch has changed, you should probably update it *before* you try to merge or rebase:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master
```

Alternatively, you can just do `git pull` if you don't mind potentially pulling in changes from other branches.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a branch from master (or the branch you want to test on)
2. Merge your pull request in this way:
   [Merge pull request to a different branch than default, in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135913/merge-pull-request-to-a-different-branch-than-default-in-github)
3. test your stuff
4. if your tests are successful, merge to master and delete your testing branch

Answer (score 1):

[Mad Physicist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42144403/1256452) is correct (and upvoted), but a diagram might help.

The key to understanding this is that for most purposes in Git, branch *names* are almost entirely irrelevant.  What matters is the *commit graph* (and the snapshots attached to each participating commit in that graph).

Let's say you have the following graph:

```
...--A--B--C         <-- mainline
         \
          D--E--F    <-- feature
```

and you are proposing to `git merge` the feature branch into the main-line branch.  Normally you would do this with:

```
git checkout mainline && git merge feature
```

which would direct Git to perform the merge ("merge" as a verb) using commits `B` and `C` as "what we did", and commits `B` and `F` as "what they did".  If all goes well Git automatically makes a *new* commit, which adjusts the label `mainline` to point *to* the new commit.  If things do not go well, Git forces us to fix up the mess (edit things in the work-tree, and `git add` the result) and make the new commit ourselves.  This also makes a new commit, which also adjusts the label `mainline` to point to the new commit.  In any case the new commit has *two* parents: commits `C` and `F` (in that order).  In other words, the new commit is *a* merge ("merge" as a noun).  So let's draw this:

```
...--A--B--C------G   <-- mainline
         \       /
          D--E--F     <-- feature
```

Now, note that this graph is identical to *this* graph:

```
          C
         / \
...--A--B   \-----G   <-- mainline
         \       /
          D--E--F     <-- feature
```

But imagine for a moment that we can make Git *not* move the label `mainline` after we make the commit, so that we get *this* graph instead:

```
          C           <-- mainline
         / \
...--A--B   \-----G   <-- ??? (HEAD)
         \       /
          D--E--F     <-- feature
```

Except for leaving the branch name `mainline` alone, the effect is *exactly the same*: we do the same merge-as-a-verb work and make the same merge-as-a-noun commit object `G`.

This is what happens if you make a new branch name (which fills in the `???` part).  The "before the new merge" picture is:

```
          C           <-- mainline, test-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B
         \
          D--E--F     <-- feature
```

and the after-merge picture is the one with merge commit `G` added.

Git knows *which* branch name to update based on `HEAD`.

Note that you can even make the merge using Git's "detached HEAD" mode.  In this mode, the name `HEAD` points *directly to* a commit ID, instead of having the `HEAD` file store the branch name.  The rest of Git works as usual, but when making a new commit, instead of updating the branch-name stored in `HEAD`—there isn't one—Git simply updates `HEAD` itself.

Once you decide that the merge is good, you can then ask Git to "slide the name `mainline` forward" in a *fast-forward* operation:

```
          C           <-- (old mainline)
         / \
...--A--B   \-----G   <-- HEAD, (new mainline if slide-forward works)
         \       /
          D--E--F     <-- feature
```

This "slide forward" operation *fails*, on purpose, if it's not possible to just slide forward.  For instance, suppose that our work to do the merge, resolving conflicts or whatever it is we had to do, and then running our tests, took a relatively long time ... and during that time, *someone else* snuck in and updated `mainline`, adding some new commit of their own:

```
          C---------H   <-- mainline
         / \
...--A--B   \-----G     <-- HEAD
         \       /
          D--E--F       <-- feature
```

It's no longer possible to "slide forward" to `G`: the name `mainline` would first have to "slide back" to `C`, losing `H`.  The fast-forward operation will fail, letting us know that our temporary merge `G` cannot become a permanent member of branch `mainline` after all.

(I've drawn the new commit `H` as an ordinary commit, but it doesn't matter whether it's a simple commit, or a merge commit: the point is that it comes after `C`, but not after `G`.  These fast-forward operations *must* move *only* "forward"—rightward, in these graph drawings.)